# Calculating Total Overtime MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I am creating a timeclock system and management website. I am trying to pull the amount of overtime for a particular department with a MySQL query.

The timeclocks update a MySQL table called events, which stores the `employee_id`, the `job` they are working on, the `time_in` and the `time_out`. I can produce a table of the total hours worked from each `employee_id` with:

```
SELECT employee_id, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in))) AS hours 
  FROM events 
 GROUP BY employee_id;
```

This will return a table of `employee_id`s and the total hours they worked. To create a table of `employee_id`s overtime I use:

```
SELECT employee_id,
       IF(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in))))>40,
          HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in))))-40,
          0) AS overtime 
  FROM events 
  GROUP BY employee_id;
```

This returns a table of `employee_id`s and the amount of overtime they have worked.

The trouble I am having starts when I want to find a total of the overtime worked for all employees. I assumed I would be able to just put the `IF` function to find overtime inside of `SUM()` however when i run the following statement:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in))))>40,
              HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in))))-40,
              0)) AS overtime 
 FROM events;
```

I get this error back:

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

I have looked all over for this but have found little in way of `SUM(IF(SUM()))` functions.

Note: The overtime has to be calculated individually, I cant just take `total hours worked / number of employees - 40`. If one worker works 30 hours in a week, and another works 50, there are 10 hours of overtime, but the average says there isn't any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT SUM(overtime)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT employee_id,
           IF(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in))))>40,
              HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in))))-40,
              0) AS overtime 
      FROM events 
     GROUP BY employee_id
  )TOTAL
```

When you're using SQL to implement complex business logic, nested queries have a key advantage: they let you test each level of the logic and build it up in a reliable way.

Comment: Thank you so much, I needed to add an alias for the inside table to avoid ERROR 1248 but after doing so it worked beautifully

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to the above answer by Ollie:

```
SELECT SUM(overtime)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT employee_id,
           IF(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in))))>40,
              HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in))))-40,
              0) AS overtime 
      FROM events
     GROUP BY employee_id
  ) TOTAL_OVERTIME
```

You need to name your derived table for the code to work.